# Gnuplot only plot a small line from file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I searched a while, but I didn't found the perfect solution for my problem.
So I'am here to ask you this:

I got a file with some measure values, date and time.
So I want to create a plotfile for gnuplot which automatically creates the plot diagram.

This is an example of the file which has to be plotted:

```
Date | Time | Temp1 | Temp 2 | Humidit
    14.01.2015|20:08:32|23.0|22.12|37.0
    14.01.2015|20:08:58|23.0|22.12|37.0
    14.01.2015|20:09:25|23.0|22.12|36.0
    14.01.2015|20:09:51|23.0|22.12|37.0
    14.01.2015|20:10:17|23.0|22.12|37.0
    14.01.2015|20:10:43|23.0|22.12|36.0
    14.01.2015|20:11:09|23.0|22.12|36.0
```

So you see the time between each measure is very short.

Here is my gnuplot file:

```
set title "Title"
set output "Diagram.png"
set terminal png size 900,600
set ylabel "Temperature in °C"
set y2label "Humidity in %"
set xlabel "Days"
set autoscale xy
set grid
set xtics
set ytics
set y2tics 25
set y2range [0:100]
set grid
set datafile separator "|"

plot  "test.txt" using 2:3 with lines title 'Temperature 1', \
      "test.txt" using 2:4 with lines title 'Temperature 2', \
      "test.txt" using 2:5 with lines title 'Humidity'
```

The result is a small vertical line from Humidity. Nothing else.
I don't get the right solution for me.

Does anyone have an idea, what I have to change in my plotfile?

Best regards
Julian

Comment: You must use `set xdata time; set timefmt "%H:%M:%S" ` to have your time data interpreted correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your file to be plotted, can you explain

Comment: Is there a way to take the second row (time) for marking the x axis?